# How can I get Google Chrome to go to an internal page without performing an external search?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, alias

I am trying to replicate some behavior that I have seen in Internet Explorer version 11 in Google Chrome version 71.

Whenever I search `myalias/someinternalpage` I am brought to the internal page.

When I search the same thing in Google Chrome's Omnibar I am taken to an external search, and at the top I am given a message, with a link, that reads

`Did you mean to go to http://myalias/someinternalpage?`

When I click on this link I will be taken to the page, and Chrome will start recognizing the alias.

This is inconvenient. How can I get Chrome to have the same behavior as Internet Explorer?

Comment: Some people report that adding a trailing slash will cause Chrome to treat it as a URL, and not as a search term. That is, try `myalias/someinternalpage/`.

Answer (score 2):

From [this Chromium.org discussion](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81226#c21), you have a few options.

> There are a few solutions, but none of them is equivalent to IE's config switch (hence the presence of this bug).
>
> (1) Enterprise policy can disable search entirely, so the Chrome address bar never searches.  This also prevents searching for less ambiguous inputs, though.
>
> (2) Users can clue Chrome in that a never-seen-before hostname is a hostname by e.g. appending a "/" to the end (or prepending a scheme, but that's more annoying to type).
>
> (3) The designed way Chrome is intended to work in this case is that when a user inputs something that is a potential intranet hostname, Chrome does a background HTTP HEAD request to that hostname, and if it gets a valid reply, it displays an infobar atop the search result page, asking "Did you mean to go to http:///?"  If a user clicks that link, not only does it navigate to this hostname now, it also remembers that hostname in the future to avoid searching again.  Similarly, doing any other successful typed navigation to that host (e.g. "hostname/" as suggested in (2)) will also cause Chrome to never search for that host again.

Comment: Is there a way to configure Chrome to already know `myalias`?

That way when Chrome is distributed to enterprise machines, users can resolve the internal web pages without the need to type a scheme or needing to type `myalias/` and then continuing on with their day by typing `myalias/someinternalpage`.

If that doesn't make sense please let me know.

Comment: Another suggestion would be to write a Chrome extension that checks searches in the Omnibar, and if it finds `myalias` it prepends the scheme and then lets Chrome handle it from there.